# unexpected line continuation character

Tags: python, kaggle

i am learning how to do data science and was following the [kaggle tutorial for titanic](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/details/getting-started-with-python).

However,

```
women_only_stats = data[                          \ #Which element           
                     (data[0::,4] == "female")    \ #is a female
                   &(data[0::,2].astype(np.float) \ #and was ith class
                         == i+1) \                       
                   &(data[0:,9].astype(np.float)  \#was greater 
                        >= j*fare_bracket_size)   \#than this bin              
                   &(data[0:,9].astype(np.float)  \#and less than
                        < (j+1)*fare_bracket_size)\#the next bin    
                      , 1]                        #in the 2nd col
```

I got this error on the first line of `(data[0::,4] == "female")`

Error:

SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Why do you have backslashes before your comments?

Comment: Is this the exact code you're running or did you add the comments just for posting?

Comment: You cannot have comments after the line continuation character - `\\` - remove the comments and try

Comment: I copied the code from here  https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/details/getting-started-with-python

Comment: The code you copied is wrong on the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code (and the code on the website you copied from) has backslashes followed by comments. E.g.

```
\ #is a female
```

The backslash is the "line continuation character". The error is telling you you shouldn't have a line continuation character followed by more text (in this case a comment).

Take out the backslashes.